# python mysql update function from tuple issue, I need your help again

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I would like to update several 10th of entries in my database. 
My idea is as follows, unfortunately, I get the following error.

I tried to convert to a string, but it does not work.

Any idea?

TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple

```
lookup={
'Gigi':'Gigi Hofleitner',
'Horst':'Horst Sergio'
}

for i in lookup:
    sql="UPDATE namen SET Name = '%s' WHERE `Name` = '%s'",((lookup[i]),i)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cursor.execute()`expects a sql statement (as string) and an optional sequence of values, so it should have been either:

```
# this build a (statement, (values,....)) tuple
args = "UPDATE namen SET Name = '%s' WHERE `Name` = '%s'",(lookup[i],i)

# so you need positional arguments unpacking:
cursor.execute(*args)
```

or

```
sql = "UPDATE namen SET Name = '%s' WHERE `Name` = '%s'"
cursor.execute(sql, (lookup[i],i))
```

For a sanitized and more readable version:

```
lookup={
    'Gigi':'Gigi Hofleitner',
    'Horst':'Horst Sergio'
}

# no need to create the same invariant string again and agin
sql="UPDATE namen SET Name=%s WHERE Name=%s"

for oldname, newname in lookup.items():
    cursor.execute(sql, (newname, oldname))

# better to commit only once    
connection.commit()
```

Comment: I had the same problem, but solved with this answer!